# Suggest Smallest Dom manipulation library for building widgets

Tags: dom, widget, javascript

Sorry 
jQuery,
Prototype,
Yahoo YUI,
Dojo don't appeal to me in when considering small. I wanted a library that would be modular has the smallest code possible upto 20Kb[un compressed] is what i expect. should provide Dom manipulation[no ajax and badass stuff] and can be extended, is widget friendly.

Comment: If you use the Google or Microsoft cached versions of jQuery, size should be a non-issue for 99% of your users.  (See http://encosia.com/3-reasons-why-you-should-let-google-host-jquery-for-you/)

Comment: @Hightechrider here's why Well 20Kb cached and minified would be better than 90Kb cached and minified to 30Kb i suppose ain't i right? Also why should my users download something that i ain't using in the app

Comment: When you use the google or microsoft CDN for common javascript libraries, such as jquery, the whole point is that your users DON'T have to download them... so no download would be better than your 20kb file in that case

Comment: @Hg3 i do accept them upto certain level, but certainly discouraging for someone who wants to explore the horizons. If Ruby 2.3[for sake i don't know exact version] is so nice and people sit and develop with that same version then there isn't going to be any improvements and developments.

Comment: A significant amount of users will have an empty cache, ~ 50% according to Yahoo: http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2007/01/04/performance-research-part-2/

Comment: This would be a more useful question without the editorializing.  I am actually looking for a minimal script to use as part of a bookmarklet,  so short of bootsrapping a library to the dom from my script a nano framework could make a big difference (I think).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are quite a few small javascript libraries on [microJS](http://microjs.com/). You may be interesting in taking a look at [$DOM](https://github.com/julienw/dollardom) (2.6kb).

Alternatively, if you want a bit more functionality while still being small, you can check out [XUI](http://xuijs.com/) (10.4kb, or 4.2kb gzipped).

Comment: i need to appreciate you for directing me, certainly chose 'xui' and 'snackjs'

Answer (score 3):

The smallest one I've seen is ender.js only 8K and it seems to handle as well as jQuery but without the baggage.

Comment: Yup and it's by Dustin Diaz one from Twitter :)